# ListBox bound to ObservableCollection not refreshing on view loaded

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I have the following XAML containing a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection

```
 <ListBox 
        Margin="0,5" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
        Visibility="{Binding ArePicturesAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConv}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPicture}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Margin="8" 
                       Height="{Binding Size.Height}"
                       Width="{Binding Size.Width}"
                       Source="{Binding FullPath, Converter={StaticResource RelativeToFullConv}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Since there is noticeable delay in populating the ListBox, I am attempting to defer this  until the ListBox's containing view has loaded using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke as illustrated below:

```
public class PictureMarkerEditorViewModel
{
    private PictureSelectorViewModel _pictureSelectorViewModel;

    public string PhotoCollectionDirectory { get; set; }

    protected ISymbolEditor GetEditorImpl(ISymbolInfo symbolInfo)
    {
        var picSymbolInfo = (PictureMarkerSymbolInfo)symbolInfo;
        _pictureSelectorViewModel = new PictureSelectorViewModel(picSymbolInfo);

        var editor = new PictureMarkerSymbolEditor(_pictureSelectorViewModel, picSymbolInfo);          
        editor.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            var photos = GetPhotoCollection();
            _pictureSelectorViewModel.Pictures.AddRange(photos);
        }));

        //var photos = GetPhotoCollection();
        //_pictureSelectorViewModel.Pictures.AddRange(photos);

        return editor;
    }    

    public IEnumerable<Picture> GetPhotoCollection()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhotoCollectionDirectory))
            return null;

        if (!Directory.Exists(PhotoCollectionDirectory))
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot show images from invalid directory " + PhotoCollectionDirectory + ".");

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(PhotoCollectionDirectory, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return files.Select(f => new Picture(Path.GetFileName(f), f, ImageUtils.GetDimensions(f)));
    }
}
```

where PictureSelectorViewModel.Pictures is simply an ObservableCollection of Picture:

```
public class PictureSelectorViewModel
{
  private readonly ObservableCollection<Picture> _pictures= new ObservableCollection<Picture>();
        public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures 
        {
            get
            {                   
                return  _pictures;
            }
        }
}
```

and Picture is a simple class containing Name and FullPath properties:

```
  public class Picture
    { 
       public string Name { get;set} 
       public string FullPath {get; set;}
       public Size Size {get;set;}
    }
```

I simply cannot get the list populated after it has loaded.  If I populate the Pictures collection before the view is loaded (the commented part of the code, I see the images.

Any one know why?

TIA.

Comment: how are you using your PictureMarkerSymbolEditor? i mean do you place it in region or directly add as a child? can you share that code?

Comment: Is the collection getting pictures from inside `BeginInvoke`? Where does `return editor` go?

Comment: I think that maybe because the collection is filled Asynchronously 
maybe Raise a PropertyChanged on "Pictures" property , when finished i'm thinking maybe the UI needs to be notified since this does not occur on the UI Thread.

Comment: @nt, the editor becomes the child of a border control that represents a region of the main window.

Comment: @Shoe, yes, the collection gets populated in BeginInvoke correctly.  If I move the two lines of code in BeginInvoke into the editor's Loaded event handler, that also fails to populate the ListBox.

Comment: @eranotzap, tried raising PropertChanged event on the "Pictures" property after updating the collection but ListBox will no refresh.  This is an interesting one.

Comment: @KlausNji have you checked the binding with snoop?

Comment: @eranotzap I have not checked the binding with snoop.  However, there are no binding errors in the output window.

Comment: Ok guys, this was silly.  Every thing was working as expected but the view model property ArePicturesAvailable bound to ListBox.Visibility  was not being updated after the Pictures collection was updated, so the ListBox was remaining collapsed.   Thanks for all the help.

Comment: for further reference you should always use snoop , you would of seen that your items source was populated , and in conclusion searched for the real problem.